# pagination and filter in mybatis

Tags: spring, pagination, filtering, mybatis

I successfully managed to use pagination when receiving data and this code works correctly

```
public Page<OrderDto> getCardOrder(Integer pageSizeValue, Integer pageNumberValue) {
        PageHelper.startPage(pageNumberValue, pageSizeValue);
            Page<OrderDto> cardOrder = orderMapper
                    .getCardOrder(docId, pageNumberValue, pageSizeValue);
        return cardOrder;
    }
```

my mybatis

```
    <resultMap id="orderResultMap" type="OrderDto" >
    <result column="id" property="id"/>
  ...
</resultMap>
<select id="getCardOrder" resultMap="orderResultMap">
    SELECT * from orders o 
</select>
```

When receiving data, I should also do a data filter, but how to do this with mybatis I cannot figure out

```
public Page<OrderDto> getCardOrder(Integer docId, Integer pageSizeValue, Integer pageNumberValue) {
    PageHelper.startPage(pageNumberValue, pageSizeValue);
        Page<OrderDto> cardOrder = orderMapper
                .getCardOrder(docId, pageNumberValue, pageSizeValue);
    return cardOrder;
}

<select id="getCardOrder" resultMap="orderResultMap">
    SELECT * from orders o WHERE o."DOC_ID" LIKE CONCAT('%',#{docId},'%')
</select>
```

this approach does not work out correctly for me and complains about the number of arguments and I cannot understand why. What am I doing wrong. thanks in advance.
Perhaps I can do filtering in a different way?

**UPDATE**

I should filter not only one field, but several. I was doing this kind of thing in Hibernate using PageRequest and getting Page in response. for example, data was sent in the fields docId = 1 and name = "Bob" and the page number and size. In response, I got those Bob with docId = 1 from the desired page. How to implement this on mybatis?

Comment: To implement custom filtering you can use Dynamic SQL in the mapper (`<where>`, `<if>`, etc.).